# select * from (select * from table)

Tags: sql, select

I have a table which records if a patron has a certain flag marked on its account. When the flag is marked it adds the flag to the patronflag table, i.e.

```
patronid   flagnumber   flagvalue
     123          200           1
```

The patron is not listed in the patronflag table if they have never had the flag.

I using the following query to find patrons who have flag 1 and but not flag 2. What I am failing to figure out is how to get patronfirst and patronlast names so I can send out a report. patronid is the primarykey and patronfirst and patronlast are the fields.

```
select getpik(patronid) from
(
Select pf.patronid from patronflags pf, pers p where pf.patronid = p.id_pers and pf.flagnumber = '2'

minus

Select pf.patronid from patronflags pf, pers p where pf.patronid = p.id_pers and pf.flagnumber = '2'
)
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Sample data and desired results are really, really helpful in explaining questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to find the patrons with flag 1 but not flag 2 using `group by` and `having`:

```
  select pf.patronid
  from patronflags pf 
  group by pf.patronid
  having sum(case when pf.flagnumber = '1' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
         sum(case when pf.flagnumber = '2' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

You can use this as a subquery and just join in the person information:

```
Select p.*
from (select pf.patronid
      from patronflags pf 
      group by pf.patronid
      having sum(case when pf.flagnumber = '1' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
             sum(case when pf.flagnumber = '2' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
     ) pf join
     pers p
     on pf.patronid = p.id_pers ;
```

You should learn proper `join` syntax.  Never use commas in the `from` clause.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I do need to study more on my SQL as its never been a true responsibility of mine.